# How to pass error array from one php file to other and display errors on top of the page?

Tags: php, arrays

How to pass error array $errors from `registrator.php` to `registracija.php` . I want to display all error on the top of the page `registracija.php`

**registrator.php**

```
<?php
    $errors = array();

        $ime=trim($_POST['ime']);
    $strLen = mb_strlen($ime, 'utf8');
    // Check stripped string
    if( $strLen < 1 ) 
    {
    $errors[] = 'Niste uneli ime.';
    }

        $prezime=trim($_POST['prezime']);
    $strLen = mb_strlen($prezime, 'utf8');
    if( $strLen < 1 ) 
    {
    $errors[] = 'Niste uneli prezime.';
    }
?>
```

**registracija.php**

```
<form action="php/registrator.php" method="post" id="regforma" name="regforma">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Prezime</td>
    <td><input class="inputKontrole" name="prezime" onKeyPress="samoSlova(event, 'prezime', '40')" placeholder="prezime" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ime</td>
    <td><input class="inputKontrole" name="ime" onKeyPress="samoSlova(event, 'ime', '40')" placeholder="ime" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a database. Save data to database from one php file and load database data in another php file. Between loading different pages all data in php code is lost.

You can also use cookies in a browser. Save cookies in one page and load them on the other.

If the second page is loaded after the first page, you can change the link to include the data you want to send in the link. For example, `registracija.php?errors="Niste uneli prezime.|Niste uneli ime."` If the array is really big you should use POST request instead of GET by using javascript or forms.